# extjs 6.0.0 Ext.chart.theme only Base & Default , How to use other themes in package

Tags: charts, themes, extjs6

when set chart theme with 'Green' , Error show

`{
xtype: 'cartesian',
reference: 'chart',
width: '100%',
height: 460,
theme: 'Green',
......
}`

Uncaught Error: [Ext.create] Singleton 'Ext.chart.theme.Green' cannot be instantiated

check Ext.chart.theme value only Base and Default ,so,we can't switch themes like the example
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#column-stacked

so , how to solve the question and use varius themes in ext package , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the requirement. Try adding `requires: [ 'Ext.chart.theme.Green']` to your class definition.